# Example for $c(fg)\neq c(f)c(g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, polynomial-rings

Let $R$ be a ring and let $f(X)$ be a nonzero polynomial in $R[X]$. The content of $f$ is the ideal $c(f)$ generated by the coefficients of f.

The ring is called Gaussian if $c(fg)=c(f)c(g)$ for all $f,g \in R[X]$.

> Do you know an example where $c(fg)\neq c(f)c(g)$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that for factorial rings, that are no principal ideal domains, your content is not the same content from Gauss' lemma. This is why there are counterexamples with factorial rings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $R=\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$. In order to see why $R[X]$ is not Gaussian, take $f(X)=g(X)=x+yX$. Then $fg=f^2=x^2+y^2X^2$ and therefore $$c(fg)=c(f^2)=\langle x^2,y^2\rangle.$$ On the other hand $$c(f)c(g)=c(f)^2=\langle x^2,y^2,xy\rangle.$$

Comment: what is $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$?

Comment: @userq...d7...6 It's the ring of polynomials in two variables ($x$ and $y$) with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ with two elements.